# C++ Defining a virtual base class overloaded operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, functor

I am trying to write a set of generic math utility classes (root finders, integrators, etc.) that take in upon construction a pointer to a base class that defines the function I want the specific algorithm to operate on. The base class should only define a public virtual interface (abstract or with default trivial functionality) `type operator()(type inputArg)` that can be implemented by the user as needed. This would allow the user to just implement the needed functors and perform the needed computations. My mwe is below:

This first header defines the abstract interface class

```
// BaseFunctor.h

#ifndef _BASE_FUNCTOR_H_
#define _BASE_FUNCTOR_H_

class BaseFunctor
{
public:
   virtual double operator() (double x) = 0;
};
#endif
```

This is the class for one of the solver methods

```
// NewtonsMethod.h

#ifndef _NEWTONS_METHOD_H_
#define _NEWTONS_METHOD_H_

class BaseFunctor;

class NewtonsMethod
{
public: 

   NewtonsMethod(BaseFunctor *rhsIn,
                 BaseFunctor *rhsPrimeIn,
                 double       x0In);

   ~NewtonsMethod();

   bool DetermineRoot(double &root);

 private:

   double       x0;
   BaseFunctor *rhs;
   BaseFunctor *rhsPrime;

   static const double       EPSILON;
   static const unsigned int MAX_ITER;

};
#endif
```

This is the solver implementation:
    // NewtonsMethod.cpp

```
#include "NewtonsMethod.h"
#include "BaseFunctor.h"
#include <cmath>

const double       NewtonsMethod::EPSILON  = 1e-9;
const unsigned int NewtonsMethod::MAX_ITER = 30;

NewtonsMethod::NewtonsMethod(BaseFunctor *rhsIn,
                             BaseFunctor *rhsPrimeIn,
                             double       x0In) :
   rhs     (rhsIn),
   rhsPrime(rhsPrimeIn),
   x0      (x0In)
{ }

NewtonsMethod::~NewtonsMethod() { }

bool NewtonsMethod::DetermineRoot(double &root)
{
   // This is obviously not implemented
   root = rhs(1.0) / rhsPrime(2.0);
   return false;
}
```

And the main function where I make the derived class implementations:
    // Main.cpp

```
#include "BaseFunctor.h"
#include "NewtonsMethod.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

class fOfX : public BaseFunctor
{
   double operator() (double x)
   {
      return x * x - 2.0;
   }
};

class fPrimeOfX : public BaseFunctor
{
   double operator() (double x)
   {
      return 2.0 * x;
   }
};


int main()
{
   double x0 = 2.0;

   BaseFunctor *f      = new fOfX();
   BaseFunctor *fPrime = new fPrimeOfX(); 

   NewtonsMethod newton(f, fPrime, x0);

   double root      = 0.0;
   bool   converged = newton.DetermineRoot(root);

   if (converged)
   {
      std::cout << "SUCCESS: root == " << std::setprecision(16) << root << std::endl;
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "FAILED: root == " << std::setprecision(16) << root << std::endl;
   }
   delete f;
   delete fPrime;
}
```

I tried to make that as brief as possible, so sorry if it is too long. Basically I get the error:

```
g++ Main.cpp NewtonsMethod.cpp -o main
NewtonsMethod.cpp: In member function ‘bool NewtonsMethod::DetermineRoot(double&)’: 
NewtonsMethod.cpp:29: error: ‘((NewtonsMethod*)this)->NewtonsMethod::rhs’ cannot be used    as a function
NewtonsMethod.cpp:29: error: ‘((NewtonsMethod*)this)->NewtonsMethod::rhsPrime’ cannot be   used as a function
```

How can I get this resolved keeping the desired functionality or deriving a class for the various needed functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rhs` and `rhsPrime` are pointers. You need to reference them in order for the function call operator to be invoked.

```
(*rhs)(1.0) / (*rhsPrime)(2.0)
```

If `rhs` and `rhsPrime` are required (i.e. cannot be NULL) and cannot be changed after the `NewtonsMethod` object has constructor you should declare them as references instead of pointers. This would also eliminate the need to dereference them to invoke the function call operator.

The example below shows how to use references to reference the functors.

```
class NewtonsMethod
{
public: 
   NewtonsMethod(BaseFunctor& rhsIn,
                 BaseFunctor& rhsPrimeIn,
                 double       x0In);

   ~NewtonsMethod();

   bool DetermineRoot(double &root);

 private:

   double       x0;
   BaseFunctor& rhs;
   BaseFunctor& rhsPrime;

   static const double       EPSILON;
   static const unsigned int MAX_ITER;
};

int main()
{
   double x0 = 2.0;

   fOfX       f;
   fPrimeOfX  fPrime;

   NewtonsMethod newton(f, fPrime, x0);
}
```

...or...

```
int main()
{
   double x0 = 2.0;

   BaseFunctor *f      = new fOfX();
   BaseFunctor *fPrime = new fPrimeOfX(); 

   NewtonsMethod newton(*f, *fPrime, x0);

   // ... other code including delete for the functors
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Dereferencing them works, although it is an ugly solution. How do I take them as references since I am referring to them as a BaseClass object? I cannot statically allocate them in main, correct?

Comment: I updated my answer to include an example for using references. You will of course still need to ensure that the functor objects have a lifetime equal to or greater than the `NewtonsMethod` object.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification. I have never had a class hold references to statically created objects as member variables (only pointers (or values...)). This works as desired and is cleaner than the dereferencing and new / deletes.

Comment: You're welcome. If you're not already familiar with the topics of lifetime and ownership I suggest you start digging into it. For instance you can use `std::vector` instead of new/delete for `char` buffers. Other times `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` _should_ be used if possible when you use `new` to create an object. There are tons of resources on SO concerning this ;)

Comment: I missed the paste of the deletes in the original post (updated now). I am familiar with shared pointers and object ownership, but haven't made the jump to C++11 so I cannot take full advantage of some of the features yet. I have gotten pretty good with valgrind though ;)